# Create table from acast function ouput [r]

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape2

I would like to create a table from acast function from `reshape2` package.
I have provided example here where I create result I need 'by hand', I need to know if there is a function to do so in R.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

mtcars %>% 
  head(6) %>% 
  add_rownames(var = "Names") %>% 
  acast(Names ~ gear)

# What I want to create is 
tibble(
  `3` = c("Hornet 4 Drive", "Hornet Sportabout", "Valiant"),
  `4` = c("Datsun 710", "Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4 Wag"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the job then:

```
head(mtcars) %>% 
  select(gear) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = gear, values_from = model) %>% 
  apply(2, unlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this will be possible. The problem is that the columns in the tibble won't have the same size. For example, for the full mtcars dataset, there will be 15 elements in the '3' column and only 12 in the '4' column.

Comment: Hi, in this example both columns 3 and 4 have same number of elements. In real data I need to perform this will always have same number of elements for each column

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @eugene100hickey 's answer but using `tidyverse` functions.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  select(gear) %>% 
  head(6) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "Names") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = gear, values_from = Names, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(everything())

#   `4`           `3`              
#  <chr>         <chr>            
#1 Mazda RX4     Hornet 4 Drive   
#2 Mazda RX4 Wag Hornet Sportabout
#3 Datsun 710    Valiant
```